# Are there any functions to subtract all features(rows) to a particular value(row) in the same data file?

Tags: r, python-2.7, math, matrix, normalization

I am new to programming in R and Python, however have some basics. I have a technical question about computation. I would like to know if there are any functions for performing subtraction of all features(rows) to a particular value (row) from the same data list. I would like to obtain the output_value1 as shown in the link below and post this, multiply by (-1) to obtain the output_value2.

*data file link*: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5rsi6ru419f5bf/Template_matrixfile.xlsx?dl=0

Please let me know if you need more details.

I have tried performing the same operation in the MS Excel, this is very tedious and time consuming.

I have many large datasets with several hundred rows and columns which becomes more complex to manually perform the same in MS Excel. Hence, I would prefer to write a code and obtain the desired outputs.

Here is the example data:Inputs are feature and value columns and outputs are Output_value1, and Output_value2 columns.

```
|Feature|   |Value| |Output_value1| |Output_value2|
|Gene_1|    |14.25633934|   |0.80100922|    |-0.80100922|
|Gene_2|    |16.88394578|   |3.42861566|    |-3.42861566|
|Gene_3|    |16.01| |2.55466988|    |-2.55466988|
|Gene_4|    |13.82329514|   |0.36796502|    |-0.36796502|
|Gene_5|    |12.96382949|   |-0.49150063|   |0.49150063|
|Normalizer|    |13.45533012|   |0| |0|


dput(head(Exampledata))
structure(list(Feature = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Gene_1", "Gene_2", 
"Gene_3", "Gene_4", "Gene_5", "Normalizer"), class = "factor"), Value = 
c(14.25633934, 16.88394578, 16.01, 13.82329514, 12.96382949, 
13.45533012), Output_value1 = c(0.80100922, 3.42861566, 2.55466988, 
0.36796502, -0.49150063, 0), Output_value2 = c(-0.80100922, 
-3.42861566, -2.55466988, -0.36796502, 0.49150063, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) along with expected output.

Comment: please include a sample of your data using `dput(head(data))` and the expected output so we can help you more easily. Some people are not comfortable clicking random links. Also do you want a python or R answer?

Comment: > dput(head(Exampledata))
structure(list(Feature = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Gene_1", 
"Gene_2", "Gene_3", "Gene_4", "Gene_5", "Normalizer"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(14.25633934, 16.88394578, 16.01, 13.82329514, 12.96382949, 
    13.45533012), Output_value1 = c(0.80100922, 3.42861566, 2.55466988, 
    0.36796502, -0.49150063, 0), Output_value2 = c(-0.80100922, 
    -3.42861566, -2.55466988, -0.36796502, 0.49150063, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")         @RAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'll only have one row where `Feature == "Normalizer"`, in R you get the `Value` of that row and subtract it from rest of the rows.

```
Exampledata$Output_value1 <- Exampledata$Value - 
                             Exampledata$Value[Exampledata$Feature == "Normalizer"]
Exampledata$Output_value2 <- Exampledata$Output_value1 * -1

Exampledata
#     Feature    Value Output_value1 Output_value2
#1     Gene_1 14.25634     0.8010092    -0.8010092
#2     Gene_2 16.88395     3.4286157    -3.4286157
#3     Gene_3 16.01000     2.5546699    -2.5546699
#4     Gene_4 13.82330     0.3679650    -0.3679650
#5     Gene_5 12.96383    -0.4915006     0.4915006
#6 Normalizer 13.45533     0.0000000     0.0000000
```

---

**EDIT**

For multiple such columns, we can do

```
cols <- grep("^Value", names(data))
inds <- which(data$Feature == "Normalizer")

data[paste0("Output", seq_along(cols))] <- data[cols] - data[rep(inds, nrow(data)),cols]
data[paste0("Output_inverted", seq_along(cols))] <- data[grep("Output", names(data))] *  -1
```

**data**

```
Exampledata <- structure(list(Feature = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Gene_1", 
"Gene_2", "Gene_3", "Gene_4", "Gene_5", "Normalizer"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(14.25633934, 16.88394578, 16.01, 13.82329514, 12.96382949, 
13.45533012)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah. Thank you Ronak. In the above, scenario, I enquired about the one column i.e "Value" However, If I have the large datasets comprising of several "Value" columns and interested in obtaining expected outputs for each "Value" column as shown above, how can I handle this type of data? Example data is below.

Comment: > dput(head(data))
structure(list(Features = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Normalizer", 
"gene_1", "gene_2", "gene_3", "gene_5"), class = "factor"), Value1 = c(21.0014918, 
19.83153625, 20.49718101, 18.97614651, 20.17378166), Value2 = c(19.56339387, 
19.50775965, 20.33358715, 19.39558316, 21.53492693), Value3 = c(19.59942404, 
18.77751314, 20.4157633, 19.19224506, 18.55032229), Value4 = c(20.83954184, 
18.21388771, 18.80596317, 19.94863527, 21.3999377)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @MohammedToufiq I have updated the answer, check **EDIT** part in the answer above. See if it works for you.